# Django Celery Tasks are not executed after an hour

Tags: python-3.x, django, celery

I'm using celery to run some background tasks in django.

Celery worker executes the tasks correctly for the first 45 minutes.
After that tasks are not executed.

I'm using Django==2.2.13 and Celery==4.4.7

And this is how i start the celery worker and beat.

```
celery worker -A app_name --loglevel=info
```

```
celery beat -A app_name --loglevel=info
```

celery setting file is:

```
CELERY_ACKS_LATE = True
CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 1
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
```

*celery.py*

```
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'app_name.settings')

app = Celery('app_name')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
app.conf.task_default_priority = 5
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'parse_sources_manager_async': {
        'task': 'parse_sources_manager_async',
        'schedule': crontab(minute=0),
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to make it work , any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of `CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE` ?

Comment: how much time will take the function to execute?

Comment: initially it works within a minute.
Later it does not work at all.

Comment: to make it work again, i have to stop the celery worker, purge all the existing tasks and have to restart.

Comment: I thin the tasks are overlapping. set `minute` to a value which is greater than the execution time.

Comment: ok, let me try that

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change the parameter of crontab(minute=59). See the documentation

< https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.schedules.html >

```
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'app_name.settings')

app = Celery('app_name')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
app.conf.task_default_priority = 5
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'parse_sources_manager_async': {
        'task': 'parse_sources_manager_async',
        'schedule': crontab(minute=59), # I changed here
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't make any difference, I fixed this using celery-singleton